# how to increment login days based on lastlogin in a mysql update query

Tags: mysql

I have following structure in a mysql table:

```
-------------------------------------
| id | username | lastlogin  | days |
-----+----------+------------+-------
| 1  | user-xyz | 2013-04-29 | 0    |
-------------------------------------
```

The above 'lastlogin' column is date column and 'days' column is int(3) column. What I want to do, while a user will login, lastlogin column will be updated everytime as usual. At the same time, the 'days' column will be incremented if the login date (when the user is logging in) is greater than the date of lastlogin column. If the user is logging in at the same day again, the days will be same (will not be updated).

What will be the mysql query in this case?

The query format will be something like this:

```
$logindate = date("Y-M-D",time());

UPDATE table
SET lastlogin=$logindate, days=days+1 if $logindate>lastlogin
WHERE usename=user-xyz
```

I posted this question previously and Vishy (one user) gave the following solution:

```
UPDATE table
SET days=DATEDIFF($logindate,lastlogin), lastlogin=$logindate
WHERE username='xyz'
```

But the code is not doing the thing exactly what I want. Because, suppose, date difference between 21 April 2013 and 30 April 2013 is 10 days. So, if a user login on 30 April 2013, it will put 10 in days column. But the user might not logged in everydays in between 21 and 30 April. He/she might have logged in 21, 23, 25, 27 & 30 April 2013, so he/she actually logged in 5days, but the above code will put 10days. The solution is to increment the value of days column whenever the user log in.

So how can I increment values in days column if login date is greater than lastlogin column by mysql update query?

Comment: if you're updating the lastlogin on each login then the query Vishy gave you is correct

Comment: @Matt, no code of Vishy was not correct in this respect. Why? Please see the explanation just below the Vishy's code. Vishy updated his answer in original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CASE expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) is handy when you want to do conditional expressions.

[SQLFiddle CASE example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96b23/1)

From that documentation I see that MySQL also has a simpler IF expression that can be used here:

[SQLFiddle IF example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87208/1)